# How to replicate a Cosmos DB container

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a very large Cosmos DB container with data as old as several years.

I want to replicate the container. As I make changes to my container, I would like the replica to be kept up to date.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/change-feed-design-patterns#data-movement) is the best way to maintain a duplicate of your container.

Note that you need to use soft deletes (tombstone flag) with change feed as a hard delete is not picked up.